# Joomla 2.5 - View not found

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5, joomla1.7

I downloaded the eventlist component for Joomla 1.7/2.5 (Component URL: http://www.joomlaos.de/option,com_remository/Itemid,41/func,fileinfo/id,6603.html)

To get output from this component I have to get to this url: [my site]/index.php?option=com_eventlist&view=categoryevents&id=1

THis worked fine! But i want to have the output only - without my site-Template!

So i added &no_html=1 to the url, because i read that this will be fix my problem. But Then there is a 500 Error (View not found [name, type, prefix]).

What did i wrong ? Thanks for your help,

Timo

Ps.: Sorry for my english ._.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

view.raw.php was missing. Problem solved